# Google Sheets Script to Delete New Rows

Tags: google-apps-script, delete-row

I am after a function to include in my RESET script that deletes any rows that the user may have added when they want to add a new item to the Google calculator I have created. I have a script that inserts a new row when a button is clicked and I have it set to insert rows after row 19.

So basically I want to reset the form to its original state but not sure how to just delete the new rows added. There are 27 possible item choices the user can choose so I can't assign a value of how many rows to delete as it will vary each time the calculator is used.

here is a screenshot of the Calculator...... so when a user clicks on the + button it adds a new row / item. So when I reset the Calculator, I want those new rows to be deleted and revert back to its default state. If I don't do this then when I hit the RESET button, the cell references and formulas etc won't match the script and will reset incorrectly. Hope this makes sense.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)  The only problem I have is that the amount of rows to delete will change depending on how many rows (items) the user adds when using the calculator.

Comment: @puffin i just uploaded a screenshot of the calculator

Comment: Could you please provide a copy of the spreadsheet you're on, clarifying the outcome you expect, and the Apps Script code you currently have?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to check if the cell `A21` is populated since only 19 rows should exist (19 rows + 1 header row + 1 extraneous row), and keep deleting rows using [`deleteRow`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleteRow(Integer)) until its empty:

```js
var sheet = SpreadshetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange("A20");

while (range.getValues().length) {
  sheet.deletRow(21);
}

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange("A21");

while (range.getValue() !== "") {
  sheet.deleteRow(21);
}
```

While this method would work it is slower than simply deleting all extraneous rows in one method call. To do this you'd want to use the [`deleteRows`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowsrowposition,-howmany) method on the active [`Sheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet). You first want to determine how many rows to delete: `sheet.getDataRange().getValues().length - 20`. Then delete that many rows from the sheet.

```js
var sheet = SpreadshetApp.getActiveSheet();
var howMany = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().length - 20

sheet.deleteRows(21, howMany);
```